# gradle error in unity exported android project

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, export

I am going to use the build config property "multiDexEnabled true" to break 64K methods limit following link 
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#about

I update to use unity 5.6.1f1 and android studio 2.3.3. I set "build system" option to "Gradle(New)", which is new added from 5.5, then click "Export" to create an android project.

I open the exported project with android studio, then I get the following error
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdrQI.png]

I try the two blue links, but I keep geting this same result.

For my unity project, I only create an empty project and add a button to a unity scene, then export it. I have also tried to build API directly, it works.

It is important for me to export unity project to andoid studio project, because it can help us to use additional compile options

Do any one know what I miss? Or how to export unity project correctly?

Thanks

The gradle error text, if cannot see the image link

Error:org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskInputs$TaskInputUnionFileCollection cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:

- Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
  **Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)**
- The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
  **Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)**
- Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Comment: why are you opening it in Android studio? you can export an apk directly with Gradle (don't use "export project"). Does it give the same error when building in this way ?

Comment: @lysergic-acid, I want to use the compile conflict option

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with unity 2017.1.0b4 and Android Studio 2.3.3, gradle 3.3.

You should change android plugin for graddle version in Android studio to 2.3.3

> You can specify the Android plugin for Gradle version in either the
>   File > Project Structure > Project menu in Android Studio, or the
>   top-level build.gradle file. The plugin version applies to all modules
>   built in that Android Studio project. The following example sets the
>   Android plugin for Gradle to version 2.3.3 from the build.gradle file:
>
> ```
> buildscript {
>   ...
>   dependencies {
>     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

Check your local `gradle` version in directory -

> C:\Users\yourname\.gradle\wrapper\dists

Modify your project gradle configuration -

> project\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

Make sure `gradle-3.3-all` match to your `gradle` version.

Answer (score 0):

If you have wasted a lot of time fixing unity Gradle error but nothing worked then you tried unity internal builder but that gave "Parsing Package error"

then try this, it will not help you make your project using unity's Gradle but it will make your project without any error successfully.

1. Export your project from unity to a folder eg: ProjectName_Gradle.
2. open android studio, make sure you are connected to the internet .
3. close current project then select "Open Gradle, eclipse ADT, etc;" option and open ProjectName_Gradle folder.
4. check the version of buildTools installed in your android-SDK by opening android-SDK settings from the android studio itself.
5. edit "build.gradle" file under Gradle Scripts section or under your project.
6. and change "buildToolsVersion" to the latest version installed in your SDK.
7. then click "syn project with Gradle Files" from file option and let it sync.
   it may ask to update Gradle version, then click update
   now there should not be any errors.
   now try building APK.